# An upper limit on the number of rules nftables can realistically process

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, nftables

I am designing a large SaaS VPN service and am planning to use nftables.

Is there a realistic limit to the number of rules it can process?

Rules will be compiled from a database. There will be thousands of nodes that will have arbitrary rules connecting them. Each node will have the option to share arbitrary ports with arbitrary other nodes. e.g. Node A can access RDP on node B. Nftables will control the security.

The process is working great in prototype. I'm really happy with how well it works. I am just concerned with scalability. I have the options of scaling up or out. But is there a point where it's going to get horribly inefficient? And at what point is that likely to be? Can it handle 10,000 rules without breaking a sweat? Or is it going to bog down?

It is currently using nftables v0.9.3 (Topsy) on Ubuntu 20.04 with Kernel 5.11.10 and Wireguard 1.0.20200513

I also realize the answer is resource and load dependant. I'm just concerned about the config architecture at the moment. Resources can always be added.

Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert by any means, as we have less than a hundred rules on our servers but such a setup with, like you said, tens of thousands of rules sounds like a recipe for disaster or weird performance issues. It's totally possible that nftables on your HW will be able to cope with this number of rules, but if I were you, I'd rethink everything to make everything more manageable. Maybe use lightweight virtualization, e.g. docker or something similar.

I haven't been able to find a surefire answer to your question but for instance Red Hat has seen quite a significant performance hit with just 1000 rules:

- https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/11/benchmarking-nftables
- https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/04/27/optimizing-iptables-nft-large-ruleset-performance-in-user-space
- http://his.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1212650/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Red Hat recommends using sets which could help manage extreme cases like yours.

Comment: In effect sets allow the number of rules to be drastically reduced, so it doesn’t increase the limit on the number of rules but it allows more endpoints to be handled ;-).